# Margin auto does not work in floating div

Tags: html, css, margin

[image]I want that the cards div are align in the center of the container div. But..as you can see as there's not as i want

Can some one help me?

If the follow html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div id="cart_image"></div>
        <div id="cart_author"></div>
        <div id="cart_desc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css code:

```
<style>

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        background: silver;
        max-width: 1400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .card {
        margin: 2px;
        width: 32%;
        height: 250px;
        background: black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "container" class, add the following CSS:

`width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;`

Should do.

Answer (score 1):

You are using px for `margin` and % for `width`, You have to use % for both.

Change card css like this:

```
.card {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 31.33%;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/p14Ln2mv/

Comment: Amazing man. it work perfectly!! Can you explain me where was the error?